# Alternative to appactivate (so SendKeys works in background)

Tags: windows, vbscript, sendkeys

I have written this script and of course every 10 seconds the 'my program' window is activated to send the <kbd>F9</kbd> key. However, what I'd like to do is send the <kbd>F9</kbd> key every 10s to the 'my program' window without actually activating it as it interupts work on other windows/browsers. Will need it to run continuously during my day as a background process ideally. (the <kbd>F9</kbd> key refreshes the screen)

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
  WshShell.AppActivate "my program"
  WshShell.SendKeys "{F9}"
  WScript.Sleep (1000 * 10)
Loop
```

Comment: SendKeys cannot do this.  You will need to pick another technology that can interact with the Windows API and use that, E.g. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+send+keys+to+unfocused+window

Comment: @Lankymart I wouldn't consider this question a duplicate, since the OP explicitly does not want to bring the window to the foreground.

Comment: Hi - i'd like to say i agree, from what i've read it's not going to be possible to parse the F9 without activating the window using vbscript (refresh.vbs file), so it'd be helpful if anyone had the next best alternative language which i could write in notepad++ and save as a file which i run in the morning and stop in the evening. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066674/alternative-to-appactivate-so-sendkeys-works-in-background#comment73218276_43066674) mentioned, [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) can only send keystrokes to the foreground window, so what you're asking simply is not possible with VBScript.